# How to Save PFFile to Object on iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfobject, pffile

I get this problem upgrading to iOS 9, the Parse Framework doesn't work completely.

I'm not able to retrive PFFiles & I'm not able to save any PFobject that has PFFile inside it.

This is my Code that was working on iOS 8.3:

```
 -(void)Save{

......
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(ProfilePicture.image, 0.5);
        NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", usernameString];
        PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:filename data:imageData];
        [user setObject:imageFile forKey:@"ProfilePicture"];


        [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {


                NSLog(@"Saved");
            }
            else{
                // Error
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];

}
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? What error is returned? Have you traced it with Charles?

Comment: Charles ?? What's that mean ?

Comment: http://www.charlesproxy.com

Comment: Is your picture greater than 10MB?

Comment: @wain the App Crashes when I try to save...and when i try to load the picture ... A I get an empty UiimageView ! I would like to tell you that I think I found the problem ! It's not because of iOS 9 but because of XCode 7...I built the app with Xcode 6.x (the last I had installed and everything is working fine)